# mysql stored procedure fails on 'END'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can't grasp as to why this won't work, i have a nearly similair procedure that works without issues, but this one just keeps throwing an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 36

```
  DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FillCnsGroupWithRates
(
    IN groupId INT(10)
)
BEGIN
    SET @var1 = groupId;
    INSERT INTO 
        cns_group_rates 
        (
            cns_id,
            other_cns_id,
            ppc,
            pps,
            max_price,
            notes,
            cns_group_id
        )
    SELECT 
        cns_id,
        other_cns_id,
        ppc,
        pps,
        max_price,
        notes,
        @var1
    FROM 
        cns_rates
    WHERE 
        cns_id NOT LIKE '319%'
    AND
        client_id IS NULL
    AND
        subordinates IS NULL
    AND
        valid_from IS NULL
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Add a  `;` before `END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget semicolon in the end of query
Try This

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FillCnsGroupWithRates
(
    IN groupId INT(10)
)
BEGIN
    SET @var1 = groupId;
    INSERT INTO 
        cns_group_rates 
        (
            cns_id,
            other_cns_id,
            ppc,
            pps,
            max_price,
            notes,
            cns_group_id
        )
    SELECT 
        cns_id,
        other_cns_id,
        ppc,
        pps,
        max_price,
        notes,
        @var1
    FROM 
        cns_rates
    WHERE 
        cns_id NOT LIKE '319%'
    AND
        client_id IS NULL
    AND
        subordinates IS NULL
    AND
        valid_from IS NULL;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can't believe i overlooked that, thanks for the quick reply, it works now

Answer (score 1):

You forgot semicolon above the end

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FillCnsGroupWithRates
(
    IN groupId INT(10)
)
BEGIN
    SET @var1 = groupId;
    INSERT INTO 
        cns_group_rates 
        (
            cns_id,
            other_cns_id,
            ppc,
            pps,
            max_price,
            notes,
            cns_group_id
        )
    SELECT 
        cns_id,
        other_cns_id,
        ppc,
        pps,
        max_price,
        notes,
        @var1
    FROM 
        cns_rates
    WHERE 
        cns_id NOT LIKE '319%'
    AND
        client_id IS NULL
    AND
        subordinates IS NULL
    AND
        valid_from IS NULL;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```